# How to preserve insertion order, constant time retrieval & dynamic resizing in java

Tags: java, javascript, arrays

I am looking to mimic Javascript arrays in Java using some sort of available data structure i.e javascript arrays lets you push/remove element dynamically there by increasing/decreasing size of your array at run time. Also they provide you constant time retrieval of any element via it's index and also maintain insertion order as well.

We have linkedList in java but they don't provide constant time lookups like arrays do though they provide dynamic resizing and maintain insertion order.

Comment: I suggest you read [The Java tutorials: List implementations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/list.html).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are looking for an [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Insertion order is preserved, lookup time is constant, resizing is dynamic and managed behind the scenes. And a simple example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(5);
list.add(10);
list.add(15);
//so on
list.get(0); //returns 5 in constant time
list.get(1); //returns 10 in constant time
```

And so on